# How to find the minimum value in a multi dimensional array matching another value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array like this,

```
[0] => Array ( [contractId] => 1 [pricingDetails] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price1 [priceId] => 1 [ageGroup] => 1 [ageFrom] => 13 [ageTo] => 50 [price] => 110.00 ) 
                    [1] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price2 [priceId] => 2 [ageGroup] => 1 [ageFrom] => 13 [ageTo] => 50 [price] => 77.00 ) 
                    [2] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price3 [priceId] => 3 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 3  [ageTo] => 12 [price] => 30.00 ) 
                    [3] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price4 [priceId] => 4 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 3 [ageTo] => 12 [price] => 30.00 ) 
                    [4] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price5 [priceId] => 5 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 3 [ageTo] => 12 [price] => 11.00 ) 
                    [5] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price6 [priceId] => 6 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 0 [ageTo] => 2 [price] => 0.00 ) 
                    [6] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price7 [priceId] => 7 [ageGroup] => 3 [ageFrom] => 51 [ageTo] => 149 [price] => 40.00 ) 
                    [7] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price8 [priceId] => 8 [ageGroup] => 3 [ageFrom] => 51 [ageTo] => 149 [price] => 30.00 ) 
                    [8] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price9 [priceId] => 9 [ageGroup] => 3 [ageFrom] => 51 [ageTo] => 149 [price] => 80.00 ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [contractId] => 2 [pricingDetails] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price1 [priceId] => 10 [ageGroup] => 1 [ageFrom] => 13 [ageTo] => 50 [price] => 120.00 ) 
                    [1] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price2 [priceId] => 11 [ageGroup] => 1 [ageFrom] => 13 [ageTo] => 50 [price] => 80.00 ) 
                    [2] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price3 [priceId] => 12 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 3 [ageTo] => 12 [price] => 35.00 ) 
                    [3] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price4 [priceId] => 13 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 3 [ageTo] => 12 [price] => 35.00 ) 
                    [4] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price5 [priceId] => 14 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 3 [ageTo] => 12 [price] => 15.00 ) 
                    [5] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price6 [priceId] => 15 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 0 [ageTo] => 2 [price] => 0.00 ) 
                    [6] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price7 [priceId] => 16 [ageGroup] => 3 [ageFrom] => 51 [ageTo] => 149 [price] => 45.00 ) 
                    [7] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price8 [priceId] => 17 [ageGroup] => 3 [ageFrom] => 51 [ageTo] => 149 [price] => 35.00 ) 
                    ) ) ))
```

I need to make an array exactly similar but containing only the lowest price value for each age group (1,2 and 3), for age group 2 there will be more (each for 0-2 and 3-12 in this example) based on different age ranges(ageFrom and ageTo).

The rest of the array structure will remain same.

The output array will be like this,

```
[0] => Array ( [contractId] => 1 [pricingDetails] => Array (  
                    [0] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price2 [priceId] => 2 [ageGroup] => 1 [ageFrom] => 13 [ageTo] => 50 [price] => 77.00 ) 
                    [1] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price5 [priceId] => 5 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 3 [ageTo] => 12 [price] => 11.00 ) 
                    [2] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price6 [priceId] => 6 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 0 [ageTo] => 2 [price] => 0.00 ) 
                    [3] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price8 [priceId] => 8 [ageGroup] => 3 [ageFrom] => 51 [ageTo] => 149 [price] => 30.00 )  
[1] => Array ( [contractId] => 2 [pricingDetails] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price2 [priceId] => 11 [ageGroup] => 1 [ageFrom] => 13 [ageTo] => 50 [price] => 80.00 ) 
                    [1] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price5 [priceId] => 14 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 3 [ageTo] => 12 [price] => 15.00 ) 
                    [2] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price6 [priceId] => 15 [ageGroup] => 2 [ageFrom] => 0 [ageTo] => 2 [price] => 0.00 ) 
                    [3] => Array ( [pricingName] => Price8 [priceId] => 17 [ageGroup] => 3 [ageFrom] => 51 [ageTo] => 149 [price] => 35.00 ) 
                    ) ) ))
```

Comment: Can you post a `var_export` instead of `print_r` of the array? And what have you done so far?

Comment: where are the codes?

Answer (score 0):

This OP has a history of not accepting any answers but I'll answer anyway. What I would do is to creating a *grouping name* so that I could then select which age group has the lowest price.

I'll create a temporary container for that. Once they are grouped, at the end of the batch. I'll flatten it, then overwrite the array with the newly grouped one.

Here's my idea:

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    $temp = array(); // create temporary grouping container for pricing details
    foreach ($value['pricingDetails'] as $pricingDetails) {
        $age_range = $pricingDetails['ageFrom'] . ' - ' . $pricingDetails['ageTo']; // this is the grouping name range that will be used in order to group each ranges
        if (
            empty($temp[$pricingDetails['ageGroup']][$age_range]) || // if not yet set
            $pricingDetails['price'] < $temp[$pricingDetails['ageGroup']][$age_range]['price'] // or if current iteration price lower than last price
        ) {
            $temp[$pricingDetails['ageGroup']][$age_range] = $pricingDetails; // assign it
        }
    }
    $temp = array_map('array_values', $temp); // key reindexing
    $new_pricing = array_reduce($temp, function ($carry, $item) { // combine all batches
        return array_merge($carry, $item);
    }, []);
    // end of batch, apply the new grouping
    $value['pricingDetails'] = $new_pricing; // assign new pricing
}
```

Here's a sample [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/FugZg)

Let me know if there's another way.

Comment: Sorry I just posted the question and not the attempted codes. But yours seems to be good. Will check on it further.